# Altering array in included file in Smarty

Tags: arrays, smarty, pass-by-reference

`main.tpl`:

```
{$array=['first']}
{include file="sub.tpl"}
{var_dump($array)}
```

`sub.tpl`:

```
{$array[]='second'}
{var_dump($array)}
```

Restults in:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'first' (length=5)
  1 => string 'second' (length=6)
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'first' (length=5)
```

How can I pass `$array` by reference, such that `'second'` is also in `$array` after the `include` is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is solution but you should really rethink your Smarty usage. Smarty should be used for displaying data only and in fact you sometimes need to create temporary variables and creating/appending to array doesn't seem to be that case.

You should always if possible prepare data to display in PHP and in Smarty simple you should display them without making complex calculations and assignment.

In your case you need to use `scope` so you should use:

```
{$array[]='second' scope='global'}
```

with scope `global` as above or scope `parent`.

However as I said it's quite possible you can do it better way in PHP.